# What to do with an unused money order?

Tags: united-states, money-order

I recently bought a money order (at Wal-Mart) to pay an overdue sewer & trash bill at my apartment complex.  But I ultimately ended up paying with a check, so didn't use the money order.

Does it make a difference (in terms of fees, availability of funds, etc.) whether I return the money order to the store, or deposit it in my bank?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fee you were charged to get the money order is gone.  You agreed to that fee when you purchased the Money order.  It is now a check that you can use how ever you wish.  If you have already added a name to the pay to line it can be changed but different agencies have different rules for what they will accept.  Take the money order to your bank explain the situation and tell them you want to put the money in your account, or cash it.